# Godot 4.2 Project Manager fonts bug on opengl3

Tags: godot4

[image]

Updated to 4.2 after 4.0 using the same workaround for running it on OpenGL3 (i.e. --rendering-driver opengl3 parameter). The font in the Project Manager ONLY has changed to this. The project editor itself and everything else is fine. Is there any way to fix this? Not critical, but it shouldn't be like that.

Comment: It looks like something to report to github: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Comment: Reported, thank you for the suggestion)